# How to prevent SQL injection of $_POST e-mail field using PHP 4

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection, php4

This would be a bit easier if I was able to use PHP 5 unfortunately this is not a viable option?

I am already using RFC 2822 from [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/11236) to validate the e-mail format is valid, granted this is using JS on the form page which is not the best practice.

I will again verify it conforms to this format before saving it but I was wondering if there were any methods that should be used to help prevent SQL injection?

Comment: "not best practise" == "entirely useless against a deliberate attack"

Comment: Not sure what you mean - protecting against SQL injection is the same in PHP 4 as it is in PHP 5. Do you mean E-Mail *header* injection?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: **STOP. NOW.** If your host doesn't allow you access to PHP 5 you need to **DROP EVERYTHING** and switch hosts immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong way - "Never trust user input"!

First be sure the data is in the format you want, then query database.
So first, check if $_POST[email_address] is in a valid email format, e.g. with regex. Only if it is in a valid email format, you query the database.

Code for email regex (PHP):

```
<?php
$email = "test@test.com";

if(eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email)) {
  echo "Email is valid.";
}
else {

  echo "Email in invalid.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Ok, read just by now, that you checked for valid format. So how do you expect the data not to be EMAIL then?

Comment: Of course, it's a good idea to validate the format, but for anything coming from the user, I would always recommend either prepared statements (which obviously isn't available in PHP 4, hence why rdlowrey's comment got so many upvotes), or at the very least escape it using `mysql_real_escape_string()` **in addition** to any sort of regex checks you might be using.

Answer (score -1):

use mysql_real_escape_string() on the input after you've validated its an email you should really be using that function on all your inputs that are going into the database.